# Missing module OpenCV Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I just installed OpenCV with [this](https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV/blob/master/Ubuntu/opencv_install.sh) script. My python code starts of with:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
    import cv2.cv as cv
ImportError: No module named cv
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

Thanks,

Tugzrida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any chance, that you're running opencv3.0 ?

the outdated cv submodule was removed, you'll have to use cv2 now.